# NativeScript Angular - How can I add an android service to handle notifications? (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service)

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to create an android service for handling Firebase messages (the [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) library does not allow me to utilize data-only messages in the background), but I cannot seem to get the service to function correctly. Specifically, I am getting the following exception when a notification is received (and sometimes when the app is started):

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.tns.services.CustomFCMService: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Cannot find object id for instance=com.tns.services.CustomFCMService@5a4269d
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3940)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:219)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

My service is defined in TypeScript as follows:

```js
@JavaProxy('com.tns.services.CustomFCMService')
class CustomFCMService extends (com.google as any).firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public init() {
    /* Do nothing */
  }

  public onMessageReceived(message: any) {
    this.super.onMessageReceived(message);
    /* Handle message receipt */
  }
}
```

I've also added changed the following my webpack file (I can provide the rest of the file if needed):

```js
// Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
const appComponents = [
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/core/android/custom-fcm-service') /* My custom service */
];
```

And lastly, I've added the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml` (inside of the `application` tag):

```xml
<service android:name="com.tns.services.CustomFCMService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I've tried changing various things in the `AndroidManifest`, service file, and webpack configuration but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Your compiler target is ES6 or ES5?

Comment: Currently `es5`. I just changed it to `es6` and got the same result.

Comment: ES5 should be fine.

Comment: When you write a constructor in Android, you will have to write a return statement like `return global.__native(this);` . Also it should be just `super.onMessageReceived(message);`, no need for `this`. Let me know if issue still priests.

Comment: I added `return global.__native(this);` in the constructor as well as removed the `this` in the `onMessageReceived` method, but the issue persists.

Comment: Can you share a repo with sample code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sure, here is a [sample repo](https://github.com/TristonJ/example-notification-service) that reproduces the issue. Please note, you will need to add a `google-services.json` in `App_Resources/Android/`, I've removed mine from the repo.

The command I am executing is `tns debug android`, and I'm running it on a physical Pixel 3 XL, the exception is occurring at app startup.

Comment: I've added code to the repo to log the push token, just like the original question, the exception also occurs when a push notification is received.

Comment: I'm unable to run the project with CLI 6.4.0, gives some issues with webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. It appears the erroneous code was inside my custom service:

```js
public init() {
    /* Do nothing */
}
```

Removing that method completely solves the issue I was having above.

It seems there is a default `init` method, that has some important implementation details such as registering object ids to instances. I noticed that when I declared that method, not only was I not calling the `super` version of it, a call to that method was also added in the constructor of the outputted .java file (which without the `init` declaration does not exist). It seems some combination of those two effects causes the exception above.